# How to apply condition in ng class for particular class?

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie for angular. I want to apply condition in ng class for particular classes.

**Here is code:-**

```
<div class="main-tb-div tab-pane fade in active" id="fdDiv">
```

I want add `in` and `active` classes dynamically.

Somethings like:-

```
<div ng-class="advisory-tab-n tab-pane fade {'in':$root.mainSegment=='fd', 'active':$root.mainSegment=='fd'}" id="fdDiv">
```

Comment: put "advisory-tab-n tab-pane fade" in class attribute of div element, and that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

> Add all static classes in `class` and dynamic class in `ng-class`.

```
<div class="advisory-tab-n tab-pane fade" ng-class="{'in':$root.mainSegment=='fd', 'active':$root.mainSegment=='fd'}" id="fdDiv">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array:

```
<div ng-class="['advisory-tab-n', 'tab-pane', 'fade', {'in':$root.mainSegment=='fd', 'active':$root.mainSegment=='fd'}]" id="fdDiv">
```

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for more info.